# Creating a Mac OS application installer from .Net Core project

Tags: macos, installation, .net-core, dmg

I am completely new to Mac OS and I have an application written in .Net Core codebase. Now all I want is to get it installed on Mac OS machines. My question is how can I create an installer (.DMG) file? At the moment My Visual Studio on Windows has created a .dll file with all other dependencies in the folder. Also for now most of the configuration values I have hard-coded but in the release build it has to be chosen by an end-user. So how can I prompt them for required directories? If you can provide me a link for documentation tool or any kind of suggestion would be greatly appreciated. At the moment if I want to run my application on Mac I have to use Terminal and then dotnet myApplication.dll in order to run application. My end goal would be to ask user for all required file paths and at the end create a System level Daemon (similar to windows service) to keep it always Alive. Would Xcode help in this situation? I already tried to open my .Net core project using xcode but it failed to load saying unsupported proect type.

Thanking in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to use the standard [macOS Installer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Installer_(macOS)) to distribute your .net Core app, you would need to create a .pkg file. There seem to be ways to do this on the console or with Third Party Tools

> sudo pkgbuild -install-location /Applications -component /path/to/your/application ./Desktop/YourPackage.pkg

There is an older [manpage for pkgbuild](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/pkgbuild.1.html), or you can try running `man pkgbuild` on your Mac.

I haven't tried this, but creating a .pkg is the normal way to install stuff on a Mac for applications where you can't just drag/drop the .app into the Application folder. (macOS applications are actually Directories with a special structure)

A .DMG is just a disk image - it doesn't "do" anything, it's just a container for files. You can create one with Disk Utility.

Comment: For some more information on .app files, this seems to be useful: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/shell-script-mac-apps